# Visual Studios running XNA 4.0 in Visual Basic and NOT in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, xna

My Visual Studios 2010 express is running XNA 4.0 in Visual Basic and  NOT in C# like i need it to.  Whenever i create a new project for an XNA game it runs it under Visual Basic instead of C#, even though i have C# installed on my machine.  I'm able to compile and run a basic program in Visual Basic and in C#, it's just that every time i try to make a new project in Visual Studios for a Windows game (or any other game) it will create it using VB instead of C#.  Any advice?

Comment: Why is this closed? The problem is clear, and the answer is rather obvious for an experienced user.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you pick the wrong language when you make the XNA project.

When you make a new project, in the "Installed templates" list, make sure you pick the "XNA Game Studio 4.0" that is in the "**Visual C#**" tab.
There is also a "XNA Game Studio 4.0" in the "Visual Basic" and it seems like it is that one you presses.

Comment: Yeah, that answer was a little basic.  Unfortunately, you didn't understand what i was asking.  I did, however, figure out the answer: The newest SDK 7.1.1 (for Windows 7, NOT Windows 8) has just an update such that it will install Visual Studios for you along with XNA 4.0 Refresh. However, if you don't already have C# installed then it will install whatever the updated version of Microsoft's default language is.  Which, as it turns out...you guessed it: Visual Basic.  It wasn't C#, surprise. I found this out the hard way. Anyone experienced should have guessed this right away

Comment: @user1789573 The question is kind of unclear, it sounded like you MADE a C# XNA project, but it is changed to VB automatically. And from what i know, that is impossible, and thus the answer would be that you ain't sure how to make a XNA project in a specific language (an therefore my answer). Nice that you figured it out tho =)